# What does [ ] mean in javascript and how to return it from C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I returned class from C# to javascript in this format

Format needed in javascript:

```
{ key: 1, label: 'Food'}
```

This part works and the class I used to return from C# looks like this:

```
public static FoodClass get_AllFood()
{
    FoodClass FoodClass = new FoodClass
    {
        label = "Food",
        key = "1",
    };
    return FoodClass;
}

public class FoodClass
{
    public FoodClass() { }

    public FoodClass(string data1, string data2)
    {
        label = data1;
        key = data2;
    }

    public string label { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public Boolean open { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I have to add a child element to my format, It has the [ ] bracket which I dont know how to get from C#

Format needed in javascript:

```
{ key: 1, label: 'Food', open: false, children: [{ key: 211, label: 'Burger' }]}
```

Comment: this should mean an array with one element, having fields key and label, so basically you can try to return collection of your `FoodClasss` as children

Comment: It looks like an array to me

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an array - in this case, with one element. Most json serializers will accept a list or array for that, so:

```
public List<Child> children {get;set;}
```

or

```
public Child[] children {get;set;}
```

where `Child` is something like:

```
public class Child {
    public int key {get;set;}
    public string label {get;set;}
}
```

You can rename `Child` to whatever makes sense without it impacting anything.

Comment: I see! I totally forgot about array.
Thanks for the crystal clear explanation